# using genetic algorithm to generate test sequences based on extended finite state machine

Tags: genetic-algorithm

I want to generate test sequences based on Extended finite state machine (EFSM ) using genetic algorithm. EFSM based testing face the problem of in feasible path by genetic algorithm. My coverage criteria is transition coverage. I have an EFSM model of a system which have input parameters and guards on transitions from one state to another. So by using this EFSM  model, I want to generate test sequences. But I am confused about how do I start. I mean how to generate initial population.
Actually, my research is about EFSM based test case generation. I have a model of ATM machine.This model consist of states and transitions. Transitions have guards and actions for the input parameters. Now I want to generate test cases for this machine. I mean model based testing. For this task it is compulsory that there should not be in feasible path. I mean every transition should be covered in test case. So for this purpose, I need to generate test sequences. Genetic algorithm is good for path optimization. but I don't know how to use my model specification in genetic algorithm and generate test sequences.

Comment: You can provide more details, like the flow of the algorithm, what you have tried/want, minimal model structures etc. Otherwise people tend to be confused and you won't probably  get any helps.

Comment: Produce a set of examples to fill your initial population and from that you should be able to come up with algorithm to produce randomised set.

Answer (score 0):

Given the ramifications I would simplify the random creation of the population part by using a random walk in the graph of FSM (not taking into account the boolean constraints for now) - this is like generation of examples from a regex (or transforming your FSM into transducer producing the input on output and walking through it). Once you generated many random examples of sufficient length, you go through a process of validating them using the _E_FSM part. Given that probably many of them will not be valid you may consider some "fixing" strategy - fixing the individuals which do not validate but are not far from being correct (a heuristic you have to come up with on your own). Then your population is actually a set of individuals (so you evolve a population of sets) and your evaluation metric would be coverage on the set level. Additionally, I would either not use crossover operator or ensure only the valid points and individuals cross. Mutation would be choosing a point in the graph and randomly going a different path. That's about it for a sketch of a solution (I successfully solved a similar problem with GA).